# Как подключить SQLite Cordova к JS-проекту?

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, typescript, cordova

Работаю с JS. Задача - подключить БД к проекту. Выбрал Cordova SQLite.
Итого, 3 ошибки (см. ниже) Как их исправить?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"

    if (window.cordova) {
        // Инициализация БД на устройстве
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "webapp5.db", iosDatabaseLocation: 'default'});
    }
    else {

        // Инициализация БД в браузере
        db = window.openDatabase("webapp5.db", '1', 'webapp5', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
    }
     
</script>
```

1. Свойство `cordova` не существует в типе `window`.
2. Не удается найти имя `$cordovaSQLite`.
3. Свойство `openDatabase` не существует в типе `window`.

Answer (score 1):

Включите скрипт перед использованием переменных

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script>
    if (window.cordova) {
        // Инициализация БД на устройстве
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "webapp5.db", iosDatabaseLocation: 'default'});
    }
    else {

        // Инициализация БД в браузере
        db = window.openDatabase("webapp5.db", '1', 'webapp5', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
    }         
</script>
```

Comment: работаю внутри app.typescript-файла . там это не нужно. нет?

Comment: похоже что нет, не нужно

Comment: в чем же дело тогда?

Comment: тэг `<script>` не был закрыт.